# $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\zeta \left( 2n\right) a^n $ simplify the given function as depending on $a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

> **Q**: $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\zeta \left( 2n\right) a^n $: 
>   simplify the given function as depending on $a$.

I tried to solve it by using Dirichlet zeta function but it didn't work I will be so gratefull if you guys prove it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view , page 59.

Comment: In other terms: apply $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides of $$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right) $$ and rearrange.

Comment: You get that for any $a\in(-1,1)$, $$ \sum_{n\geq 1} \zeta(2n)\,a^{2n} = \frac{1-\pi a \cot(\pi a)}{2}.$$

Comment: So as I understood we can put a conplex number instead of "a"

Comment: that is how power series work.

Comment: I think that there is a typo in your last formula @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @user243301: which typo? It should be correct.

Comment: I think that the limit as $a\to0$ isn't correct, any case I see the formula in DLMF @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @user243301: the limit as $x\to 0$ of $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ is $1$, which is precisely the product $\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$ evaluated at $x=0$. I do not really get what the issue is.

Comment: And the limit of $\frac{1-\pi a\cot(\pi a)}{2}$ as $a\to 0$ is zero, as it should be.

Comment: Oh, now I see my mistake @JackD'Aurizio I'm sorry.